# Plotting Windrose from csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv, windrose

I would like to plot a windrose from data in .csv file.
From the Windrose documentation, it looks like I need the wind speed, wind direction, and date as index column (csv [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kTa_oKgCMfw-QTTkWCINhF16cd8Uo6cp/view?usp=sharing)).

I tried multiple ways around it but always run into errors.
The error I have now: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Should I just leave out the index column or what would be the best option to plot a windrose from csv?

```
from windrose import WindroseAxes
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from windrose import plot_windrose

df = pd.read_csv("Wind2.csv",index_col='Date', names = ["Date", "speed", "direction"], sep=";")

ws = df["speed"].values
wd = df["direction"].values

plot_windrose(df, kind='contour', bins=np.arange(0.01,8,1), cmap=cm.hot, lw=3)
plot.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have missing data - for instance, in line 182970, you're missing speed data.

Try manually filtering or filling in the data, or try using [pandas' filter function](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) to remove the offending lines.

Comment: Thanks! That was actually a lot easier than expected.
Didn't think of that...